# Easiest way to create a CRUD with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP (used to Python) and I've been instructed to create something that will allow users to CRUD entries. I was originally going to use a textarea field and sort by which numbered row they were, but I realized that if a user deleted a row, that it would screw up all the UIDs for the whole system.

So now here I am, several hours into the project and trying to figure out what's the best way to create something which A) allows multiple rows of data B) allows this information to be deleted or updated C) allows additional rows to be added D) shows all the rows available (this can be scrollable, so that it all doesn't display at once)

Database is MySQL

Are any of these easy to integrate? I don't know quite how much access I have to the server that this is running on.

Comment: are you using some kind of db? mysql maybe? [This is where it begins for you](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/)

Comment: I don't get your question. Where do you want to store the data? What do you mean with textarea field and numbered rows?

Comment: Are you looking for an ActiveRecord implementation in PHP?

Comment: did you notice the complete working code I posted in your other answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider looking at a framework that comes with prototyping or scaffolding support like CakePHP. Besides PHPMyAdmin, that's probably the fastest way of getting CRUD functionality to work with an existing datastore.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit overkill, but you can very quickly get a basic and flexible CRUD up and running by installing [CodeIgniter](http://CodeIgniter.com/) and then [GroceryCRUD](http://www.grocerycrud.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Some PHP frameworks come with built-in CRUD, but since OP didn't ask for any specific framework, then my answer recommends a framework-agnostic CRUD.

[Agile UI](https://github.com/atk4/ui) is an open-source PHP UI component library containing CRUD, Grid, Form, Menu and many other visual elements you can use out-of-the box.

15 lines of PHP, (no HTML and no boilerplate code) is enough [to build this](https://github.com/atk4/ui#admincrud-in-15-lines) UI:

[image]

Here is full code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \atk4\ui\App('My App');
$app->initLayout(new \atk4\ui\Layout\Admin());

$db = \atk4\data\Persistence::connect($DSN);

class User extends \atk4\data\Model {
    public $table = 'user';
    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('name');
        $this->addField('email', ['required'=>true]);
        $this->addField('password', ['type'=>'password']);
    }
}

$app->layout->add(new \atk4\ui\CRUD())
    ->setModel(new User($db));
```

You'll need to also run: `composer require atk4/ui` but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the yiiframework. It design is pythonesque like. The Gii generator that comes with Yii will read you DB tables and create all the necessary CRUD code for some simple editing.

http://www.yiiframework.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a drop-in admin like this too, here's one I found so far:

http://ajaxcrud.com/